# Converted HTML data into and get error excel cannot open the file

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export-to-excel

I have made a code to convert HTML table data into an excel file and it works fine. It creates the file successfully

**So what's the problem**

When I try to open the excel file it shows an error that says.

> Excel cannot open the file filename.xlsx because the file format or
> the file extension not valid.

Below is the code that I am using

**HTML Code**

```
<table id="tblexportData" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Robert</td>
            <td>robert@gmail.com</td>
            <td>26</td>
             <td>9999999999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>michael@gmail.com</td>
             <td>24</td>
             <td>9999999999</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Julie</td>
            <td>julie@gmail.com</td>
             <td>36</td>
             <td>9999999999</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>Trevor</td>
            <td>trevor@gmail.com</td>
             <td>28</td>
             <td>9999999999</td>
        </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>

<button onclick="exportToExcel('tblexportData', 'user-data')" class="btn btn-success example-screen">Export Table Data To Excel File</button>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function exportToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
        var downloadurl;
        var dataFileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
        var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var tableHTMLData = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

        console.log(tableSelect.outerHTML);
        console.log(tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20'));
        // Specify file name
        filename = filename?filename+'.xlsx':'export_excel_data.xlsx';
        
        // Create download link element
        downloadurl = document.createElement("a");
        
        document.body.appendChild(downloadurl);
        
        if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
            console.log('msSave if');
            var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTMLData], {
                type: dataFileType
            });
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
        }else{
            console.log('msSave else');
            // Create a link to the file
            downloadurl.href = 'data:' + dataFileType + ', ' + tableHTMLData;
        
            // Setting the file name
            downloadurl.download = filename;
            
            //triggering the function
            downloadurl.click();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** - I have tried `application/vnd.ms-excel` for xls and it is working but I is not working with `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` i.e. for xlsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using kendo-UI it native support export to excel export.
[kendo Excell](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export)

if not, I'm using this method:

```
   $scope.exportData = function () {
    debugger;
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet ><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayRightToLeft/><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    if ($scope.mororList)
        var table = document.getElementById("Grid");
    else
        var table = document.getElementById("OtherGrid");


    var filters = $('.k-header .k-grid-toolbar').remove();
    var newtable =  table.childNodes[1].innerHTML + table.childNodes[2].innerHTML

    newtable = "<table style='direction:rtl'>" + newtable + "</table>";
    $('.k-rtl .k-grid .k-widget').after(filters);
    var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: newtable };

    var url = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'excelName.xls';
    a.target = "_blank";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.onclick = "aclickfn";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    setTimeout(function () {
       
    }, 200);

};
```

Comment: No i am not using kendo ui. I am using pure javascipt and jquery